# Excel VBA: Hide or show rows - differences between US English Excel and German edition?

Tags: excel, vba

the following code should hide or show certain rows in Excel 2016. It does as intended in the German Excel version but for my US colleagues who use the US English Excel version just nothing happens. No error message, no stop of code - nothing.

Is there some difference between the versions I am not aware of? Unfortunately I cannot debug it on a US machine.

Row_SMLlookup is an integer having the actual row I want to hide/unhide.

```
Public Function displaySMLsearch(show As Boolean)

    If show Then
    
        Worksheets("Requirements").Rows(Row_SMLlookup).Hidden = False 

    Else
    
        Worksheets("Requirements").Rows(Row_SMLlookup).Hidden = True 
    
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: How is this called? Right now this not a [reprex].

Comment: Is `Row_SMLlookup` a module level variable? Note that since you said its an `Integer` and you are using it to represent row number, you should declare it as `Long` as the amount of row numbers can be larger than what `Integer` can holds and thus cause overflow error.

Comment: Test it by just replacing `Row_SMLlookup` with a number. Shouldn't be any difference between languages.

Comment: And personally, I'd want it as a sub, since it's not returning anything. And replacing the whole thing with just `Worksheets("Requirements").Rows(Row_SMLlookup).Hidden = Not show`

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Row_SMLlookup is a ```public const``` within the module. I already replaced it with just a figure, unfortunately with no effect.